# Rails project failing to push to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm following this [tutorial](http://docs.railsbridge.org/installfest/create_and_deploy_a_rails_app?back=create_a_heroku_account#step5) and my application is failing to push to Heroku. Here is the output I get when I try to push it:

```
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       no implicit conversion of String into Hash
       /tmp/build_4b2bc135-54ea-4d31-a9f3-7a58601a5aa6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispat
ch/routing/mapper.rb:254:in `merge'
       /tmp/build_4b2bc135-54ea-4d31-a9f3-7a58601a5aa6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispat
ch/routing/mapper.rb:254:in `root'
       /tmp/build_4b2bc135-54ea-4d31-a9f3-7a58601a5aa6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispat
ch/routing/mapper.rb:1321:in `root'
       /tmp/build_4b2bc135-54ea-4d31-a9f3-7a58601a5aa6/config/routes.rb:54:in `block in <top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_4b2bc135-54ea-4d31-a9f3-7a58601a5aa6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispat
ch/routing/route_set.rb:289:in `instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_4b2bc135-54ea-4d31-a9f3-7a58601a5aa6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispat
ch/routing/route_set.rb:289:in `eval_block'
       /tmp/build_4b2bc135-54ea-4d31-a9f3-7a58601a5aa6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispat
ch/routing/route_set.rb:267:in `draw'
       /tmp/build_4b2bc135-54ea-4d31-a9f3-7a58601a5aa6/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_4b2bc135-54ea-4d31-a9f3-7a58601a5aa6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_sup
port/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
       /tmp/build_4b2bc135-54ea-4d31-a9f3-7a58601a5aa6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_sup
port/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
       /tmp/build_4b2bc135-54ea-4d31-a9f3-7a58601a5aa6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_sup
port/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_4b2bc135-54ea-4d31-a9f3-7a58601a5aa6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_sup
port/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
       /tmp/build_4b2bc135-54ea-4d31-a9f3-7a58601a5aa6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/applicati
on/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
       /tmp/build_4b2bc135-54ea-4d31-a9f3-7a58601a5aa6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/applicati
on/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
       /tmp/build_4b2bc135-54ea-4d31-a9f3-7a58601a5aa6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/applicati
on/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
       /tmp/build_4b2bc135-54ea-4d31-a9f3-7a58601a5aa6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/applicati
on/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
       /tmp/build_4b2bc135-54ea-4d31-a9f3-7a58601a5aa6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/applicati
on/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
       /tmp/build_4b2bc135-54ea-4d31-a9f3-7a58601a5aa6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_sup
port/file_update_checker.rb:78:in `call'
       /tmp/build_4b2bc135-54ea-4d31-a9f3-7a58601a5aa6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_sup
port/file_update_checker.rb:78:in `execute'
       /tmp/build_4b2bc135-54ea-4d31-a9f3-7a58601a5aa6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/applicati
on/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
       /tmp/build_4b2bc135-54ea-4d31-a9f3-7a58601a5aa6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/applicati
on/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
       /tmp/build_4b2bc135-54ea-4d31-a9f3-7a58601a5aa6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/applicati
on/finisher.rb:66:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
       /tmp/build_4b2bc135-54ea-4d31-a9f3-7a58601a5aa6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializ
able.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_4b2bc135-54ea-4d31-a9f3-7a58601a5aa6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializ
able.rb:30:in `run'
       /tmp/build_4b2bc135-54ea-4d31-a9f3-7a58601a5aa6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializ
able.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_4b2bc135-54ea-4d31-a9f3-7a58601a5aa6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializ
able.rb:54:in `each'
       /tmp/build_4b2bc135-54ea-4d31-a9f3-7a58601a5aa6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializ
able.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_4b2bc135-54ea-4d31-a9f3-7a58601a5aa6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/applicati
on.rb:136:in `initialize!'
       /tmp/build_4b2bc135-54ea-4d31-a9f3-7a58601a5aa6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/c
onfigurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
       /tmp/build_4b2bc135-54ea-4d31-a9f3-7a58601a5aa6/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_4b2bc135-54ea-4d31-a9f3-7a58601a5aa6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/applicati
on.rb:103:in `require'
       /tmp/build_4b2bc135-54ea-4d31-a9f3-7a58601a5aa6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/applicati
on.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
       /tmp/build_4b2bc135-54ea-4d31-a9f3-7a58601a5aa6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/applicati
on.rb:297:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
       /tmp/build_4b2bc135-54ea-4d31-a9f3-7a58601a5aa6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/ass
ets.rake:93:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_4b2bc135-54ea-4d31-a9f3-7a58601a5aa6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/ass
ets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_4b2bc135-54ea-4d31-a9f3-7a58601a5aa6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/ass
ets.rake:23:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
       /tmp/build_4b2bc135-54ea-4d31-a9f3-7a58601a5aa6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/ass
ets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
       Tasks: TOP => environment
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:fast-plains-3333.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

Edit:

```
Here is my environment.rb

# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
TestApp::Application.initialize!
```

Comment: Can you show what's in your `config/environment.rb` file, particularly line 5?

Comment: Also, do you get the same error when you run (locally): `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`?

Comment: Added it at the bottom

Comment: strange, the rake db:migrate stopped working now as well

Comment: Something wrong with routes.. line no 54.. Please paste

Answer (score 1):

[precompiling-assets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets)

Add this into your `config/application.rb` file

```
  config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```